# Clips explode$ not functioning correctly when receiving input from the user

Tags: rules, clips

Hi i have written a defrule that is suppoesed to simulate a propositional law but the defrule is not firing when i give it the correct input.

I believe that the explode$ may be adding ome spaces but i am not sure how to remove them

```
     CLIPS (Cypher Beta 8/21/18)
CLIPS> (batch "AI taak.txt")
TRUE
CLIPS> (deftemplate andprop (slot symbol1)(slot symbol2))
CLIPS> (deftemplate orprop (slot symbol1)(slot symbol2))
CLIPS> (deftemplate implies (multislot premise)(multislot implication))
CLIPS> (deftemplate sentence (multislot sent))
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-from-user
=>
(printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies 
please " crlf)
 (bind ?response (explode$ (readline)))
(assert (sentence (sent ?response))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule negative
(sentence (sent "~" "(" "~" ?symbol ")"))
 =>
   (printout t "HI " ?symbol crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please 
~(~P)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (sentence (sent ~ ( ~ P )))
For a total of 1 fact.
```

So in theory the negative rule should fire but it isn#t. An help in figuring out why would be appreciated. thx

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the explode$ function was tweaked in 6.4 for tokens that normally act as delimiters to convert them to symbols rather than strings. This was done so that exploding a string and then imploding the result produced a string without additional quotations.

This is what used to occur with 6.3:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> (implode$ (explode$ "~(~P)"))
""~" "(" "~" P ")""
CLIPS>
```

And this is what occurs with 6.4:

```
         CLIPS (Cypher Beta 8/21/18)
CLIPS> (implode$ (explode$ "~(~P)"))
"~ ( ~ P )"
CLIPS>
```

You can get the results you had before by using the replace-member$ function in read-from-user rule to replace the symbols with strings:

```
         CLIPS (Cypher Beta 8/21/18)
CLIPS> (deftemplate sentence (multislot sent))
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-from-user
   =>
   (printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please " crlf)
   (bind ?response (explode$ (readline)))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "(" (sym-cat "(")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response ")" (sym-cat ")")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "~" (sym-cat "~")))
   (assert (sentence (sent ?response))))
CLIPS> (run)
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please 
~(~P)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (sentence (sent "~" "(" "~" P ")"))
For a total of 1 fact.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working now if i only enter ~(~P) but i would like the program to accept any string containing this order of letters. Is there any way i can alter the code to accept any strings before or after the _(_X)? Thank you for your help